Top horizontal scrollbar
Currently, the app I am working on has a horizontal scroll bar on the top of the app (something similar to Amazon’s top scroll bar). However, the names of the pages/categories are quite long, so the users will need to scroll for a long time to see the whole bar.
Is it better to change the whole design into a side menu panel or try to cut the words down (which is a quite hard)?
Thanks!


Amazon can get away with this because they're Amazon. People persevere with it even if they're annoyed because they know Amazon is what they want to use. If it annoys 1000 people a day who then just quit it won't even make a noticible difference to Amazon.
You are not Amazon.
If your navigation items and structure don't fit with your chosen navigation pattern, change the pattern. Your navigation pattern should be chosen based on the structure of the site / app. Not the other way around.
I can't tell you what pattern you should use. That's going to be based on the structure and items. But there are many other options you could look at that work better on smaller screens. Burger menu. In-page links. Dropdowns... Find the pattern that fits your structure.

Thanks for your feedback! After doing some user testings, we decided to move onto new navigation pattern
